# Blackberry - UI like BBM

Tags: layout, blackberry, user-interface, java-me

I want to make a layout like Blackberry Messenger.

Is it possible to add ListField to a TreeField in Blackberry?

Alternatively, if I use ListstyleButtonField, how can I get the expand and collapse state so I can add the ListField on the expand event.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to add a ListField to a TreeField, since TreeField acts like a ListField using a callback.

I'd use a `VerticalFieldManager` in combination with `CheckboxField`s, adding the different ListFields corresponding to the states of the Checkboxes.

If u want to use `ListstyleButtonField` you need to extend it by some kind of boolean state, changing its value on `clickButton` before the `fieldchangenotify`.